# Realm Sync offline-first on React Native: how to implement?

Tags: mongodb, react-native, realm, offline

I am working on an [offline-first](https://www.mongodb.com/collateral/the-offline-first-approach-to-mobile-app-development) app with Realm Sync on React Native.

The specific programming problem I want to solve is how to implement this offline-first behaviour with React Native in my app, so that a logged in user will have a seamless experience whether online or offline. I am looking for code which illustrates best practices for offline-first with Realm Sync which implements this.

The otherwise excellent Realm documentation is very limited when it comes to offline-first and the [demo app in the MongoDB Realm documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/tutorial/react-native/) implements Sync, but is not designed to be offline capable. Naturally my starting point was that app, as it it the one recommended in the documentation as well as on the forum.

I have tested both the iOS Swift and the React Native 'Task Tracker' app and they are not offline-first capable as currently implemented, which their engineers confirmed to.

The significant code in `TaskProvider.js` from that app is:

```js
useEffect(() => {
    const config = {
      sync: {
        user: user,
        partitionValue: projectPartition,
      },
    };
    // open a realm for this particular project
    Realm.open(config).then((projectRealm) => {
      realmRef.current = projectRealm;

      const syncTasks = projectRealm.objects("Task");
      let sortedTasks = syncTasks.sorted("name");
      setTasks([...sortedTasks]);
      sortedTasks.addListener(() => {
        setTasks([...sortedTasks]);
      });
    });

    // ...
  }, [user, projectPartition]);
```

Since I need to use code like this in my own app, the first question is how to change this code to perform properly for offline-first usage. Additionally if you have gotten an offline-first Realm Sync app to work on React Native please provide a link or relevant example code.

Comment: The question is a bit unclear but it may because of the terminology. When the words *Realm Sync* are used, that indicates a situation where the app is, as always, offline first but also has an online sync'ing component. The Task Tracker app stores all of its data *on your device* (offline) and then sync's in the background, it's definitely offline first.  The Realm Sync Tutorial is just that - for *Sync* situations. If you want to focus on locally stored data, ignore that and just go through the regular [Quick Start](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/sdk/react-native/quick-start-local/) guide.

Comment: Oh, just so you know if the question is closed (not by me) that asking for tutorials is considered OT - from the [Help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) *Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.* - so rephrasing the question might be a good idea.

Comment: @Jay you apparently have never tried any of the Task Tracker example apps on the site. i have tested both the iOS Swift and the React Native 'Task Tracker' app linked above and they are definitely not offline-first capable as currently implemented. - Try to disconnect from the network while in the 'Projects' view of the app. Then click on 'My Project' which is supposed to display a list of tasks. In React Native it will show an empty list while the iOS Swift implementation will just stop responding while offline.

Comment: @Jay There is a difference between what Real Sync is capable of in theory (which I agree is 'offline-first') and what is demonstrated in the example Task Tracker app which has almost no usable offline functionality. If you are well versed in Realm Sync programming please share some example code where you have actually implemented this. - After some research, I have created a PR which will make the Task Tracker app more offline-capable than the current implementation. - I could almost rephrase my question as a bug report, as this could be considered a bug for an offline-first platform.

Comment: An additional data point to consider: I have a TaskTracker app that closely mirrors the one in the Swift tutorial. I installed the app on a MacBook and ran it. I logged into my account within the app and created two tasks, then checked the Realm Console after a couple of seconds and they were there (sync'd). I then turned WiFi off - simulating a network interruption. I created two more tasks within the app to check "offline first". Finally, I re-enabled wireless and within a couple of seconds Realm did it's job and sync'd the two tasks up to the server. So it's working for me as it should.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the question revolves around a bug in an off-site tutorial app and is also "Seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more" which is off topic for StackOverflow.

Comment: Well the MongoDB Realm Sync demo app is not just any random 'off-site tutorial app, but part of the core documentation for Realm Sync where new users are systematically directed to in various ways. When first using these SDKs (iOS and React Native) I do not expect that the reason that a core feature is non-functional, is due to a bug or a wrongly designed demo app. I asked the question, because I am planning to switch my current app project (which is in development) from Firestore to Realm Sync and I could find no properly working example code that actually shows offline-first working.

Comment: Understood. We went through the same process about 6 years ago. Still a Firebase developer but it didn't fit our model. Please see [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) - *Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow* and *Questions asking for customer support with third-party services are off-topic.*. We try to keep questions here code specific that can be solved with code from our users. Again, good catch and I am glad Mongo addressed it with a new version.

Comment: @Jay - I have already rephrased the question twice, so that it fits within SO guidelines and I do not believe that the current version of this question is off-topic. I do appreciate that it drew your attention due to your in-depth experience with Realm and Firebase and I likely will be asking more targeted questions in the future as I transfer my app from Firestore to Realm. I do notice that Realm Sync questions  are not as well covered on SO, especially relating to React Native. This is quite different from questions with regard to Firebase/Firestore and React Native.

Answer (score 2):

I submitted a PR which makes the example [Task Tracker App by MongoDB Realm Sync](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/tutorial/react-native/) more offline capable. This is not a complete solution, but it deals with the main issue of the task lists becoming inaccessible while offline.

One significant point is that to sync changes in the background Realm needs to be opened synchronously not asynchronously.

The new code for `TaskProvider.js` with comments from the documentation linked below:

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    // You may want to sync changes in the background to display partial data to
    // the user while the synced realm downloads data from the server,
    // preventing the user experience from being blocked. We recommend syncing
    // changes in the background for applications in which the user's device
    // may go offline.
    const OpenRealmBehaviorConfiguration = {
      type: 'openImmediately',
    };
    // Create a Configuration object, which must include the sync property
    // defining a SyncConfiguration object. Set this
    // OpenRealmBehaviorConfiguration object as the value for the
    // newRealmFileBehavior and existingRealmFileBehavior fields of
    // the SyncConfiguration.
    const config = {
      sync: {
        user: user,
        partitionValue: projectPartition,
        // The behavior to use when this is the first time opening a realm.
        newRealmFileBehavior: OpenRealmBehaviorConfiguration,
        // The behavior to use when a realm file already exists locally,
        // i.e. you have previously opened the realm.
        existingRealmFileBehavior: OpenRealmBehaviorConfiguration,
      },
    };

    // open a realm for this particular project
    Realm.open(config).then((projectRealm) => {
      realmRef.current = projectRealm;

      const syncTasks = projectRealm.objects('Task');
      let sortedTasks = syncTasks.sorted('name');
      setTasks([...sortedTasks]);
      sortedTasks.addListener(() => {
        setTasks([...sortedTasks]);
      });
    });

    //...
  }, [user, projectPartition]);
```

[Sync Changes Between Devices - React Native SDK — MongoDB Realm](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/sdk/react-native/examples/sync-changes-between-devices/#sync-changes-in-the-background)

More details here: [enable offline-first in TaskProvider, syncing changes in the background by agape-apps · Pull Request #9 · mongodb-university/realm-tutorial-react-native · GitHub](https://github.com/mongodb-university/realm-tutorial-react-native/pull/9)

This still has significant limitations as stated in the PR. Therefore I continue to look for more complete implementation details or code samples from those who have used Realm Sync with React Native for an offline-first app.

Comment: In the swift version, tasks are readily available when offline - just tested it live.

Comment: Great you tested the Swift version as well. Is that the unmodified Task Tracker demo app I linked to, or your own implementation which you mention in the comment above? Your own implementation might differ in offline-first capability. --- I am running the unmodified Task Tracker demo app right now in an online/offline test: I disconnect from the network while in the *Projects* view of the app. Then click on 'My Project' which is supposed to display a list of tasks. The app just stops responding while offline. It will not go to the tasks list and log errors. (continued...)

Comment: It's pretty much a clone - the only difference is I am running it on macOS so some of the UI elements differ slightly (UITextField vs NSTextField) etc. That being said, I've been working with Realm for a LOT of years so my project is probably based on code from a year or so ago. Let me grab the current version and try it out.

Comment: The error shown is: "Task Tracker[7805:412271] Sync: Connection[18]: Failed to connect to 'ws.realm.mongodb.com:443': All endpoints failed". The only screen that works offline is the "My Project's Tasks" screen where I can add tasks and they will be uploaded when I go back online. But if I leave that screen, I cannot return to it while offline, even though I am still logged in. - I described this reproducible behaviour to the Engineers at MongoDB as well and they confirmed it for React Native via their customer support promising an improved version in a few weeks.

Comment: It sounds like you may have found a bug in the tutorial app (thank you for that!); if so, it's just bad coding on their part. But that's not related to whether realm is designed to be an offline first database. From the question: "Your data is always written locally and then sync'd to the server While this is stated in the marketing material, **this is not the case**" - doesn't go along with what you just said *where I can add tasks and they will be uploaded when I go back online*. See? A blatant bug in how they wrote the demo app doesn't correspond to Realm not writing data offline first.

Comment: Looking at the repo, it appears they have corrected the code in the React Native tutorial so thanks for catching that!

Comment: I eventually found a solution for the Swift version as well. Apparently the demo app was never designed to demonstrate offline-first capability, just like the React Native version. They are using `Realm.asyncOpen()`, for which their documentation states: "When you use asyncOpen, you should first check for a network connection. If the app is offline, asyncOpen leaves your app waiting forever." This actually describes the offline experience of the current version quite well. - I fixed it by changing it to open Realm *synchronously*. Is that how you implemented it in your app, Jay?